# Multiple connection strings to the same database performance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Recently I was working on an asp.net mvc 4 application and when reviewing the application I noticed I had 2 connection strings that pointed to the same database.

**ApplicationServices** - For membership related stuff

**MyDbEntities** - For entitry framework related stuff

I know you can make the entity framework context point to the applicationservices connectionstring like below I guess

```
public MyDbContext() : base("name=NameOfYourConnectionString") //  Name of your connection string
{ }
```

Is there any performance difference between having one connection string vs defininf multiple connection strings? Or is ASP.NET smart enough to know the database is the same and will share connection when need be?

Regards DotnetShadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any performance difference between having one connection
>   string vs defininf multiple connection strings?

The [`ADO.NET connection pool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) is per connection string. There will be a difference only if the connection strings have some differences. In this case you will have 2 different connection pools instead of reusing connections from the same pool which would have been better since you are hitting the same database. But if the 2 connection strings are strictly identical, there will be no difference.

Comment: Can you provide insight about "strict identical"? Can extra blankspace spoil the picture?